# R function to filter / subset (programatically) multiple values over one variable

Tags: r, subset

Is there a function that takes one dataset, one col, one operator, but several values to evaluate a condition?

```
v1 <- c(1:3)
v2 <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- data.frame(v1, v2)
```

Options to subset (programmatically)

```
result <- df[df$v2 == "a" | df$v2 == "b", ]
result
1  1  a
2  2  b
```

Or, for more robustness

```
result1 <- df[ df[[2]] == "a" | df[[2]] == "b", ]
result1
  v1 v2
1  1  a
2  2  b
```

Alternatively, for easier syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
result2 <- filter(df, v2 == "a" | v2 == "b")
result2
  v1 v2
1  1  a
2  2  b
```

(Am I right to assume that I can safely use dplyr's filter() inside a function?
)

I did not include subset() above as it is known to be for interactive use only.

In all the cases above, one has to repeat the condition (`v2 == "a" | v2 == "b"`).

I'm looking for a function to which I could pass a vector to the argument, like `c("a", "b")` because I would like to pass a large number of values, and automate the process.

Such function could perhaps be something like:

`fun(df, col = v2, operator = "|", value = c("a", "b")`

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `%in%` if the number of elements to check is more than 1.

```
df[df$v2 %in% c('a', 'b'),]
#   v1 v2
#1  1  a
#2  2  b
```

Or if we use `subset`, the `df$` can be removed

```
subset(df, v2 %in% c('a', 'b'))
```

Or the `dplyr::filter`

```
filter(df, v2 %in% c('a', 'b'))
```

This can be wrapped in a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, col, val){
 filter(dat, col %in%  val)
 }

f1(df, v2, c('a', 'b'))
#  v1 v2
#1  1  a
#2  2  b
```

If we need to use `==`, we could loop the `vector` to compare in a `list` and use `Reduce` with `|`

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(letters[1:2], `==`, df$v2)),]
```

Comment: thanks for that. It does solve the issue as it takes 1 or more elements. isn't the opposite of %in%, !%in% ? I think I've used it before. Any idea why it would throw an error inside a function? Thanks

Comment: @jpinelo You may have to try `filter(df, !v2 %in% c('a', 'b'))`